# Visual Studio 11 Windows 8 Metro App with COM Extension

Tags: c#, com, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

I got so annoying problem, that can't be solved by just googling for me :((

I have a Windows Metro App, that must use a third-party COM-object for checking an answer from remote server, but I can't add reference to it directly in Metro App.

I think I need to build some kind of Windows service, maybe WCF Service Library (from which I can add this COM object), but I don't know how to connect this service with my Metro App. MSDN's docs are so exhausting, that I get lost in this amount of abstruse words... MY GOD!!!

And I want to build this apps without using IIS or something like this..

Simply bald Windows 8 and my installed app - and it must work of course :)

Thank you everyone in advance.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Metro apps support WCF service. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/piyushjo/archive/2011/09/22/wcf-in-win8-metro-styled-apps-absolutely-supported.aspx. Where are you stuck? elaborate clearly

Comment: Sorry, you will need a server process, and at the end of the day IIS is the recommended way to host them. Or you self-host, which is not a lot less work but a lot less.... convenient.

Comment: Thank you both, men. but I can't understand, why do I need to put my libraries over IIS. I just want to use some methods from my COM object and get the answers from it... then, just visualize received data in my Metro App. Can't I just create Windows Service (as simple background process) and collect the data from it in my Metro App?

Comment: i have no idea of COM. For inter process communication, WCF is required. IPC over metro apps is constrained, and should be done using share charm only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are all right, men. Thank you everyone!

Everything what I needed is to create a WCF Library and reference it to my COM object (but be very sure that your COM is not 32bit, otherwise you need to patch your WCFServiceTest app).

Then you simply dialoguing your app&service with data/operation contracts and that's all.

simply genius.